# Selenium FirefoxDriver in Headless get error

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xvfb

I'm getting the following error when I try to open the Firefox in headless mode:

```
Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port
7055; process output follows:

(process:27527): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed
Xlib: extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".

(firefox:27527): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-VBJDTHN8W2: Connection refused
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'cpro22808', ip: '176.153.5.11', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-32-generic', java.version:
'1.7.0_55'

Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04, Firefox 33, Selenium 2.44, Tomcat7, Xvfb.

I'm starting the Xvfb like that:

```
Xvfb :1 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24
```

My java code:

```
String Xport = System.getProperty("lmportal.xvfb.id", ":1");
FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
firefoxBinary.setEnvironmentProperty("DISPLAY", Xport);
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxBinary, null);
```

I spent several days on this and tried a lot of things and nothing solve. Can someone help me?

Comment: make sure you are using compatible selenium and firefox versions

Comment: Yes, I did. Thats is why I talked about the versions in the post. I also tryed firefox 28 with selenium 2.41, and I get the same error. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: can you attach to display :1 by starting firefox from the command line? Have you tried a different display value? I let jenkins and maven handle this, but generally use display :2 onwards

Comment: the error is common with version incompatibilities.

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing the same problem. This is what I did and the problem is gone.

1. Delete `/var/lib/dbus/machine-id`. It will recreate a correct one on its one.
2. `export $(dbus-launch)` and `export NSS_USE_SHARED_DB=ENABLED`. Set these environment variables and then re-run.

The issue was gone in my case.

Comment: Thank you so much @saresh you saved my day! https://github.com/elgalu/docker-selenium/blob/2.53.1z/bin/entry.sh#L6

Answer (score 0):

That's a good solution but at the end I discovered another option without the need of launching dbus. You can instead disable the logging of geckodriver with `-Dwebdriver.firefox.logfile=/dev/null` system property.

Curiously I could pass it from command line, but I had to explicitly set it before instantiating the FirefoxDriver:

```
    System.setProperty(FirefoxDriver.SystemProperty.BROWSER_LOGFILE, "/dev/null");
    FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
```

The drawback is that you lose also any other log, but I like the fact that you don't need to run dbus-daemon.